# custom keyboard keytext shadow remove

Tags: android, background, keyboard, preview, android-keypad

i have used the custom keyboard app from the sdk and modified it as per my requirments but i couldn't modify two things

1. remove drop shadow from the key text of every key on the key board. as i did not find any property in xml layout which i could use
2. i have used custom layout for keyopreview that is the popup shown when we press any key on the keyboard, but i dont want to show preview for some particular keys such as space, enter, shift, back etc. so how could i remove the keypriview fot only those keys..

[image]

Answer (score 26):

well i found the answer.

well in the keyboard view xml put `android:shadowRadius="0.0"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
    ...
    android:shadowRadius="0.0" />
```

Comment: You save my time. Thanks dear for posting the answer.

Comment: Thanks from me too!